# How to have jQuery detect wether first input is text or not and fire the jQuery if it is text

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want this jQuery to only fire after actual text (not something like a backspace or tab is pressed) is inputted into the search bar, so that not all the possible search results will display from my database.

```
function searchq() {
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
    $.post("search.php",{searchVal:searchTxt,}, function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
    });
}
```

Here is the input:

```
<input id='input' type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Here..." onkeydown="searchq();" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an if condition based off of the results of trim:

```
if(searchTxt.trim() != '') {
    // do your post
```

[`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) will remove whitespace from both ends of the string. If a tab or a space is the only thing in the value, the result of `trim` will be an empty string.

As @Karl-André Gagnon pointed out in his comment, there is also a [jQuery-specific function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) you can use to trim whitespace:

```
if($.trim(searchTxt) != '') {
```

Comment: jQuery also have its own function which work on all browser : `$.trim(searchTxt)`

Comment: HELP!                                                                    When I input this it says 
" ReferenceError: Can't find variable: searchTxt " This is when I put it after the function searchq() completely @watcher

Comment: You need that check inside of the function searchq, and it needs to be _before_ you send the post.  Variables in javascript are scoped to the function they are in, you wont have access to them outside of the function they are declared.

Comment: @watcher wow thanks ALOT for the help, I have been trying to fix that forever now.

Answer (score 0):

Test whether the input is not empty

```
if (searchText != '') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you add more detail to your answer? While short answers may help by pointing in the right direction, it would be helpful to have further explanation.

Comment: Not sure what more I can say about such a simple question and answer.

Comment: You could link to relevant documentation, show multiple ways of doing it (html `required` attribute, CSS visual indicators with `:valid`, perhaps a jQuery solution, different ECMAScript syntaxes that do the same thing…), and/or provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: That's way more work than seems necessary for something that's so incredibly obvious. Some questions just don't deserve long-winded answers. I barely thought that my first sentence was necessary.